# When running python script background, the job always stops

Tags: python, bash, ffmpeg, background, subprocess

I wrote a python script, "download_vod.py" that runs a child process using subprocess module.

download_vod.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
url = xxx
filename = xxx.mp4

cmd = "ffmpeg -i " + url + " -c:v copy -c:a copy " + "\"" + filename + "\""
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
proc.wait()
```

When I run foreground on a bash shell as below, it works fine and terminates properly

> ./download_vod.py

But a problem occurs when I run the script background as below.

> ./download_vod.py&

The script always stops as below.

> [1]+  Stopped                 download_vod.py

If I resume the job as below, it resumes and terminates properly.

> bg

I assume it is caused by running subprocess because it never happens without subprocess.

Would you let me know what happens to the subprocess (child process) when I run the python script as background? And how would it be fixed?

Comment: You should try invoking ffmpeg with the **-nostdin** flag.

Comment: It works correct!! Now the script does not stop when run on background!! <br>Thank you for your prompt and correct answer.